# Ошибка при копировании данных в динамических массивах

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Я не пойму как в динамических массивах правильно скопировать данные из одного го столбца в другой (не переадресовать их адрес в из другова массива)

```
    //создание 
int ***temp = new int**[WeyListIntOfClass];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < WeyListIntOfClass; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = new int*[strintRaport];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < strintRaport; ++j)
        {
            temp[i][j] = new int[2];
        }
    }

    int **ptrarray = new int*[strintRaport];
    for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++)
        ptrarray[count] = new int[2];

/*Как то какие то действие ввели*/

//копируем
    for (int i = 0; i < strintRaport; i++)
    {
        ptrarray[i][0] = temp[0][i][0];
    }
```

Comment: Вам надо нарисовать кубик temp и таблицу ptrarray. Указать на них соответствующие индексы и размерности строк, столбцов и так далее, и все получится.

Comment: @ Alexander Chernin  ты не понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно бы все и ничего, только вот вы сначала создаете массив

```
temp[WeyListIntOfClass][strintRaport][2]
```

Потом *пытаетесь* создать

```
ptarray[strintRaport][2]
```

но ограничиваетесь только

```
ptarray[2][2]
```

Понятно, что при копировании после двух элементов у вас начинаются неприятности. Может, попробуете так?

```
int **ptrarray = new int*[strintRaport];
for (int count = 0; count < strintRaport; count++)
    ptrarray[count] = new int[2];
```

P.S. Вы же работаете в C++ - почему не воспользоваться `vector`?..

Comment: я как бы в универе учусь и по заданию создать динамический массив с указателями, а вектор когда я принес мне сказали не правильно.

Comment: Ну, тогда дело другое...